# Bypass filtering in bash for "." and "space"

Tags: bash, ubuntu

i am trying to bypass . filtering , so is there any way to write . and the bash shell can understand it ?

for example i can bypass space by using :

```
cat</etc/passwd

{cat,/etc/passwd}
```

thanks

Comment: What does it mean to `bypass space`?

Comment: for example i can't run this command cat / etc/passwd but i can run this cat</etc/passwd

Comment: It looks like you are trying to exploit a server. Do you want to write commands which fit a character whitelist on the server? (A terrible security measure, by the way, as you are demonstrating.) Specifically, are you trying to *source* a script using dot notation?

Comment: yes this what i am trying to do please read this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351331/how-to-send-a-command-with-arguments-without-spaces i want ti do the same but with " . "

Comment: Can you not just run the script? Does it have to be sourced?

Comment: `{.,filename}` is equivalent to `. filename`

Comment: yes i know :) but the problem is i can't use .

Comment: Are you sure the shell in use is really bash, not `/bin/sh`? Brace expansion is a bashism, so `sh -c '{.,filename}'` won't treat the braces as special. (That said, I'm not convinced that this question is actually topical here; you're not *developing* software, you're trying to figure out how to exploit someone else's. It's useful for software developers to understand why bad ideas attack mitigation techniques are bad, but that doesn't necessarily make them on topic here).

Comment: BTW, one approach you can take here is to capture a space from another program's output into a variable, and then use that variable.

Comment: (`source` is a bashism, too; a baseline POSIX `/bin/sh` implementation won't honor it).

Answer (score 2):

In Bash you can use the `source` keyword:

```
$ cat some_script
echo sourced
$ {source,some_script}
sourced
```

Comment: Rename the script, `test` is also a valid name.

Comment: i can't rename any file

Comment: How do you put the script on the server?

Comment: You could use `$'...'` strings to not use a dot literal, e.g. `{source,$'test\x2esh'}`

Comment: @MahmoudKhatib To get a good answer, you should specify all of your requirements (like filtering of `'`) up front in the question.